# Is it necessary to opto-isolate a darlington array output?

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, esp8266, darlington, transistor-array

I've got the following circuit going:

A Vishay opto-isolator (CNY74-4) that takes input from buttons that work on 24V, and outputs to microcontroller pins (an Olimex ESP32-PoE-ISO in my case).

A ULN2803 darlington array connected to the microcontroller, +24V and GND, driving LEDs.

Initially I had designed the circuit so that the 24V of the buttons had its own separated GND. But to use the ULN2803, I need to connect the GND of the microcontroller to the GND of the 24V power supply, or it won't work.

This entire setup works perfectly, but I'm wondering if I should also put an opto-isolator between the microcontroller and the ULN2803. It might be overkill, but then the 24V power supply is completely separated electrically from the microcontroller.

I discovered the Vishay ILQ30, an opto-isolator with darlington output. It could take care of this in one DIP. Or the Toshiba TLP627-4, that one is in my KiCad library :)[image: Image of the schematic]

Comment: *A Vishay opto-isolator ... that takes input from buttons* OK, to describe circuits we use a **schematic** please include one.

Comment: The schematic is divided over multiple sheets in KiCad - I have time later tonight to draw a clear one for this question and include it.

Comment: Try the `edit` button below the question and click the schematic button. Pretty easy to use. :)

Comment: There is no environmental need defined in your question for an opto. isolator.  (overkill)

Comment: To add to Tony's comment - what are you attempting to protect against that would require the isolator? ESD? PSU noise? Spikes from motor drive?

Comment: Just potential short circuits that would send 24V through the microcontroller somehow.

Comment: I've included the schematic, deleted all other buttons and kept one. The button here is a 4-pin JST connector that goes to a button with a 12V LED.